# ADFS 2.0 StandAlone service account for SQL attribute store

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, adfs

I am trying to set up a stand alone ADFS instance with a SQL attribute store.  I have gotten ADFS 2.0 to work, but when adding a SQL store using integrated authentication, it cannot connect (the SQL server is on a separate server) because it is running as Network Service (I get the login failure as DOMAIN\server$ tried logging in).

Is there any way to set up a SQL store in a stand alone environment (using WID) with integrated authentication?  I know you can specify credentials when installing a farm, but this option is not available when setting up a stand alone instance.  (I am also not a domain admin so I can't set up a farm, and this is a POC so getting the domain admins involved will raise a lot of questions for a test.)  I am trying to avoid using SQL logins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt seem to be possible to create a login for a computer using SQL studio GUI option (disclaimer I am no SQL guy). But I tried using Transact-SQL to do this and made a login. Used following syntax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<computername$>] FROM WINDOWS; GO
```

Replace computer and domain name as applicable.

If you define access to the database for this login, you may be able to use as an attribute store while using standalone option. Please report back if this fails.

Comment: I can't since I don't have domain admin privileges, and to set up a farm you need to be able to create AD objects.  It looks like I will be stuck using either a connection string login or getting the domain admins involved.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on a new method to create a login to represent a computer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I will give it a shot shortly and see if it works.